# SAS Studio - Count and filter over multiple columns from a macro variable list

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, sas-studio

I am currently checking a large number of tables for linking keys(all with different names) between datasets. My current code checks for how many records exist and for how many records have a 0 key value. My code looks like this:

```
%let table = table1;
proc sql;
create table linking_keys as
select * 
from work.my_datasets
where Table_Name = "&table" 
and linking_key NE 'N';
quit;

proc sql;
select Column_Name
into :lnkkeycol separated by ','
from linking_keys;
quit;

%put &lnkkeycol;
proc sql;
create table lnk_key_only as
select count(*)
from library1.&table;
quit;

proc sql;
create table lnk_key_only_2 as
select count(&lnkkeycol)
from library1.&table
where &lnkkeycol = 0;
quit;
```

This works fine when there is only 1 linking key in the table, but when there is multiple, it falls over. I have tried grouping by macro variables but not had much success with the below:

```
proc sql;
create table lnk_key_only_2 as
select count(&lnkkeycol)
from library1.&table
where &lnkkeycol = 0
group by &lnkkeycol;
quit;
```

I am not entirely sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify each link key column separately. If you have multiple link key columns, you are passing this into the `count()` function:

`count(col1, col2, col3)`

Which is invalid for the `count()` function. Instead, create a separate macro variable that counts each link key col only when its value is 0.

```
proc sql;
    select cats('sum( (', column_name, '=0) ) as count_', column_name)
    into :lnkkeycol separated by ','
    from linking_keys;
quit;
```

This will create individual `sum()` functions that will only count the condition where `column_name = 0`. `(boolean conditon)` is a shortcut in SAS that creates a 1/0 value if the condition is true or false. If we encapsulate it in a sum function, `sum( (boolean condition) )`, we can sum only the 1's.

```
proc sql;
    create table lnk_key_only_2 as
    select &lnkkeycol
    from library1.&table;
quit;
```

This translates into:

```
proc sql;
    create table lnk_key_only_2 as
       select sum( (col1=0) ) as count_col1
            , sum( (col2=0) ) as count_col2
            , sum( (col3=0) ) as count_col3
    from library1.&table;
quit;
```

Comment: That would force SAS to invent names for the three count() function result variables.  Also if you are counting only the observations that have COL1=0 and COL2=0 and COL3=0 then then all three of the COUNT() results will be the exact same number, the number of observations with all three variables equal to zero.

Comment: Probably should change it from AND to OR? I need some sample data to try it out.

Comment: Updated it to sum only the boolean condition (coln=0)

Comment: Thanks for the solution Stu, I actually figured out a slightly different method a bit before you replied but I appreciate your help again.